# I can not make a query work, I need another eyes to look it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have 3 columns and what I need to do is a query where I can see
Lab name, Sum Job count **only N**, Sum redos only **Y**.
I tried with array, but not let me get the conditional Col2=N,
Please help me.

`=query({A2:B,ArrayFormula(if(C2:C="y", B2:B,0))}, "select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3) where Col1 <> and Col2 ='N', '' group by Col1 label sum(Col2)'', sum(Col3)''", 0)`

[image]

Comment: If using a pivot table is an option, it would be much easier done than by using queries and array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown where your posted sample resides in the spreadsheet, so I'll assume that the header "Lab Name" is in A1 with the rest taking up the top of range A:C. Given this, the following formula should work:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({A2:A,B2:B*(C2:C="N"),B2:B*(C2:C="Y")},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2), SUM(Col3) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) '', SUM(Col3) ''"))`